# What happens when an IP address isn't found in the IP to Nation database?

Tags: ip, iptonation

I have a site where a few people are reporting that all they get is a blank page when they visit it. This started happening after we put some country detection code on there that showed tweaked content depending on the country that you were viewing from. We're using the IP to Nation module in EE to handle this and have kept the database up to date.

I'm wondering whether it is possible that the blank pages could be a result of their IP address not being found in the database? Could this happen?

I'm using the MC Country plugin in conjunction with the IP to Nation module (MC Country requires this). Here's a snippet of code that I'm using on all pages:

```
{if "{exp:mc_country default='gb'}" =="gb"}Call us <i>free</i> on +44 (0)800 014 8201 from 8am to 8pm{/if}
{if "{exp:mc_country default='gb'}" !="gb"}Call our offices in Portugal on (+351) 308 800 878{/if}
```

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Jim

Comment: Could you post the code that you use to show the tweaked content depending on the IP?

Answer (score 1):

A blank page typically indicates a hidden error, likely a PHP error. Since you are using a tag inside quotes of a conditional, my guess is that the MC Country plugin is returning something that is causing a malformed conditional. My suggestion would be to use the [native IP to Nation tag](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/ip_to_nation/#type-text) using the parameter `type="text"` to get the country code.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted Derek's suggestion as it makes sense and is most likely the way to go. But you might want to try making the condition a bit simpler.

The way you have coded it, if you first condition isn't true then the second condition will always be true. So you don't need 2 if statements. Try using if:else to simplify your conditional.

My understanding is that you want to show the Portuguese details if the visitor is not in Britain right? So try something like this to make it simpler and may reveal the error.

```
{if "{exp:mc_country default='gb'}" != "gb"}
    Call our offices in Portugal on (+351) 308 800 878
{if:else}
    Call us <i>free</i> on +44 (0)800 014 8201 from 8am to 8pm
{/if}
```

What this says is, if the country code isn't 'gb' then show the Portuguese details, fall back to 'gb' if no code is returned. If no code is returned then default to 'gb' (and so show the 'gb' details.